# HiveMQ broker issue: Same config, failed to connect with devboard (CONNACK returns 5), successful connection with desktop client

Tags: mqtt, iot

Was trying to get my IOT devboard to log in to an MQTT cluster I use on HiveMQ. Failed. MQTTX desktop client connected fine.

Checked the dev board's unencrypted CONNECT message, which should be correctly formatted, and if SSL screws up the message encryption, theoretically there shouldn't even be a CONNACK and connection should be closed immediately. So what's actually happening? Any quick way to troubleshoot?

Broker configs (mostly stock, without using command line): Allows subscribe+publish, SSL enabled by default, ClientID can be anything, Port 8883

Desktop client MQTTX configs: SSL connection, MQTT version 3.1.1, Port 8883

IOT dev board configs: Uses a rudimentary MQTT library. Uses AT commands to wrap data in SSL and send. MQTT version 3.1.1, address and password settings are correct. Can connect to another private MQTT broker if SSL is disabled.

Desktop client connected fine.
IOT dev board failed to connect, and received the broker's CONNACK data saying error code 5 (Not authorized)

Comment: What is output to the [broker logs](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/4.13/user-guide/logging.html) when you attempt to connect? Have you confirmed that the CONNECT packet sent by MQTTX is identical to that sent by the devboard? Have you tried simplifying things by connecting to a single instance of Hive rather than a cluster? Without more info it's difficult to comment (there are a number of situations where 5 will be returned - [for example](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/4.13/user-guide/configuration.html#_connections_with_will)).

Comment: I'm quite new to this but I'll give as much info as I could:
1. Haven't configured the HiveMQ CLI desktop app to use the HiveMQ cloud cluster. Might test it.
2. Cannot prove it. My desktop MQTTX client sends data over regular ethernet, while the IOT devboard sends data over 4G cellular. Likely even if the unencrypted CONNECT message is the same, they will be encrypted differently as they're sent over different routes.

Comment: Checked the examples shown. There's no Will setting available through the data packet. The HiveMQ cloud cluster is lax on this setting anyway.

Comment: OK - so you are using HiveMQ Cloud cluster (I don't think this makes logs available which makes tracking down issues a bit more difficult!). If you share your code (with passwords redacted) we may spot something but currently there is really not enough info. The fact that you are receiving a CONNACK appears to indicate that the device has successfully establishing a TLS connection. Perhaps try [test.mosquitto.org:8885](https://test.mosquitto.org/).

Comment: @Brits Mosquitto connection worked! It's password-bound so password misconfiguration on my devboard can't be the issue. I checked the documents on HiveMQ, which didn't solve anything (For one thing, there's really no extra settings conflicting here)

Comment: Probably time to talk with HiveMQ support; they should be able to check logs to see why your connection is failing (unfortunately there is insufficient info here to offer other suggestions).